I have an issue with latex on sublime text 3 where it writes ``'' instead of " or ""
basilicaly it writes two ` and two ' insead of ". This only happens in when I write latex on sublime text 3. I tried adding "smart_quates":false in sublime text settings and LaTeXTools settings but nothing changed.

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every post, even in the original one. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/79013720/2777074

you should almost never have " in a latex document always \`or''`  so the editor  behaviour does not seem unreasonable but you haven't really given much indication (and I can't help with that editor as I do not have it.)

I deleted the other post because I believe it was more suitable to this site

Okay, I will use `` '' I guess. I didn't thought about that but it's a good idea as well.

The reason this happens is that TeX knows to translate those characters into the appropriate opening/closing quote marks.  It doesn't know what to do with ", so it always translates that into closing quotes.

@Teepeemm or more exactly it doesn't translate them at all so in legacy OT1 encoding you get closing quotes, in other font encodings you might get straight quotes
